# how to pass input to multiple ARNs (aws step function)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to figure out how to pass multiple input to my ARN's. However it seems i cannot do that.

Below is my machine specification

```
{
    "StartAt": "DemoStateFunction",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "States": {
        "DemoStateFunction": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "ARN-Demo-Function",
            "InputPath": "$.demostate1",
            "Next": "DemoStateFunction2"
        },
        "DemoStateFunction2": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "ARN-Demo-Function",
            "InputPath": "$.demostate2",
            "End": true         
        }
    }
}
```

and this are my input

```
{
    "demostate1": {
        "data": "john",
    },
    "demostate2": {
        "data": "doe"
    }
}
```

When executing this task. It succesfully retrieve my demostate1 data, however it seems it cant see demostate2 as i am seeing on "TaskStateEntered" step.

Comment: Is the lambda that is executed in DemoStateFunction returning a value for demostate2?

Comment: hi chris. no. i am not returning any value for demostate2 since it doesn't need it (in my scenario at least).

Answer (score 6):

Machine state data is passed from one state to another.

If you return data from your task and don't specify a `ResultPath` property on your state, then the task's output becomes the input of the next state. This is where your `demostate2` is being lost.

From: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-input-output-processing.html

> the task results are sent along as the state's output (which becomes the input for the next task).

So, you'll want to merge the result from `DemoStateFunction` into the input data by using something like this on your `DemoStateFunction` state:

```
    "DemoStateFunction": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "ARN-Demo-Function",
        "InputPath": "$.demostate1",
        "ResultPath": "$.demooutput1",
        "Next": "DemoStateFunction2"
    },
```

This takes the result from the task and merges it into the existing input structure under the `demooutput1` property.